# better way to write this program so that it consumes minimum time to execute

Tags: php, execution

I want the same result with less execution time. Is there any better way to write the code so that I can get the same result with minimum execution time.

```
<?php
     $input1 = 5;
     $input2 = 1;
     $input3 = [9, 5, 10];

    $numberOfWalls = count($input3);
    $numberOfJumps = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<$numberOfWalls; $i++){
        if($input1 >= $input3[$i]){
            $numberOfJumps += 1;
        }else {
            $tot = 0;
            while(1){
                if($tot + $input1 < $input3[$i]){
                    $tot = $tot + ($input1 - $input2);
                    $numberOfJumps += 1;
                }else{
                    $tot = $tot + $input1;
                    $numberOfJumps += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $numberOfJumps;
```

Comment: If we were to rewrite your code we would at least have to know what its purpose it. What the input and output should be, what it does, and why. It whould also be nice to know why it takes to long now, and what kind of time reduction you're seeking. Most of the time the best advice is: Buy a faster computer.

Comment: This program was given in a coding contest. In this $input3 was an array which contains height of walls. Input1 was the height which a monkey can jump and input2 was the the height he slips when he was unable to cross the wall. I wrote this program and I score 100/100 but the execution time was 0.94sec and the best result was 0.14sec. I was curious how can I write this program with minimum execution time.

Comment: Clearly the best way is not to loop, but to solve this little puzzle mathematically. One jump is `$input1 - $input2` high, so you can compute how many jumps are needed to cross a wall. PS: I would not have given your a score of 100/100. You me the way a solution is found is as important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
// input
$forwards  = 5;
$backwards = 1;
$walls     = [9, 5, 10];
// computation
$oneJump   = $forwards-$backwards;
$jumps     = 0;
foreach ($walls as $wall) $jumps += ceil(($wall-$backwards)/$oneJump);
// output
echo "Jumps needed = $jumps";
```